# How to hide a certain value in a DonutChart in TeeChart when value is null?

Tags: .net, teechart

I have a donut with 5 values. Some of the values become 0 at a certain moment. When I draw the TeeChart with only ONE value (and others are 0) then it shows a horizontal line in the donut (if one of the middle values is different from 0). How can I control whether a value within a DonutSerie is visible or not?

Answer (score 1):

The Donut will draw a line even when adding in only one value. To stop this happening, you can set the Pen to invisible, e.g.

```
private void InitializeChart()
{
  Donut series = new Donut(tChart1.Chart);
  series.Add(1);

  series.Pen.Visible = false;
}
```